# Does anyone know of an embeddable video player that plays m3u8 video files?

Tags: html, video-streaming

I'm trying to find an embeddable HTML5 video player that recognizes and plays m3u8 files to be viewed on a website, so we can use the same video resources we're already creating for mobile deployment.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Video elements support a small collection of Video encapsulations, thus your video will have to be encoded a few times to be fully playable cross platform.

[DiveIntoHTML5 Video](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works) has a compatibility table of what Formats are available on different browsers.

Simple video example;

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4" />
  <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="pr6.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
  <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "http://wearehugh.com/dih5/good/bbb_480p.mp4", "autoPlay":false, "autoBuffering":true}}' />
    <p>Download video as <a href="pr6.mp4">MP4</a>, <a href="pr6.webm">WebM</a>, or <a href="pr6.ogv">Ogg</a>.</p>
  </object>
</video>
```